# Google maps custom tiles set up and non-displaying of images

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm completely new to javascript and the google API's in general. I want to show the tiles which make up the game map of IL2 Cliffs of Dover on a webpage, using the google maps methodology. This is complicated as the coordinate system is not the same, and in fact the images appear to be upside down but I'll come on to that later.

I've seen the example here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

and copied the code out into a new file. I then changed the code to the following, making changes to the path and the tile size (190 not 256)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image map types</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>

var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
      if (!normalizedCoord) {
        return null;
      }
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);

if (typeof(console) !== "undefined" && console.log) { // prevent errors when console not open, ideally all console calls should be removed before going into production
            console.log(normalizedCoord.x);
        }
      return 'http://stormofwar.org/images/m4_' + normalizedCoord.x + '-0.jpg';   
      // return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
          // '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
          // (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(190, 190),
  maxZoom: 4,
  minZoom: 0,
  radius: 190,
  name: 'Moon'
};

var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(moonTypeOptions);

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 1,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['moon']
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As far as I can see from the debug console log via firebug, the variable normalizedCoord.x is being set to 1 or 0.

I've changed the format of the tile filenames to be m4_x-y.

If I hard code the file to a specific example, say m4_0-0.jpg, then it shows (multiple times across - of course because it's hard coded, but seemingly 2 rows for some reason?) However, if I leave it to do it's own thing, I get absolutely no image. I'd have thought at least I'd get one image somewhere?

I don't know what to do now, I can't see what is wrong as I'm just not familiar with JS. Ideally, I'd prefer not to have to doctor the images at all, which are TGA files, and as I say numbered differently to the google example AND upside down (no rotation though which is odd!)

Comment: I should point out, at this stage I'm not concerned about zoom. I'm just trying to get a single level of zoom detail to display. The zoom can come shortly! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think you can change the tile size to 190*190. 256*256 is the grid on Google's basic map canvas. 
Secondly, your image will pan in respect to your zoom levels. Pay attention to this comment:

> // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
>     // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc

You mentioned you want to take care of zoom levels later on but you tiles will load based on the zoom level you gave. For example:  at zoom level 0 - 1 tile; for zoom level 1 - 2 tiles and so forth.

And lastly, when you hardcode and you get two rows is one of the rows cropped by 124 pixels (either from all edges or a set thereof)? Because I think what's happening there is since you hardcoded it is being loaded but its being split on the basic grids to accommodate.

Hope this helps.

PS: Here's an [article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-google-maps-api-and-custom-overlays--webdesign-13868) that should help clarify the whole concept.